# Best ways to browse a SVN with Zend Framework

Tags: php, svn, zend-framework

I would like to know what are the best ways/practices to browse a SVN (like http://core.svn.wordpress.org/) with Zend Framework. As a student learning Zend Framework, I am not very used with this framework so I would like to start on the right direction. It has to do simple tasks like list all files, retrieve a revision of a file, get the latest revision. I already found the "[phpsvnclient](http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/)" class, but I dont know if it's the best way with Zend. If you have feedback on all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF has no package for reading SVNs. You would have to use another library for this to go along with ZF. Since ZF uses a use-at-will architecture, you should be able to use any library side by side. Basically, the SVN is just a datasource, like a DB table or a folder or a webservice, which is why the package will use should be part of your model, which you access through your controllers.

Possible alternatives:

- http://tracker.arbitracker.org/vcs_wrapper/documentation/view/Start
- http://pecl.php.net/package/svn
- http://pear.php.net/package/VersionControl_SVN

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and advice. I am going to check these ressources !